# A blackbox testing frame with testing management system

Tags: python, testing, frameworks, vmware

Is there a testing framework (preferable python) that executes test, monitor the progress (failed/passed/timeout) and controls the vmware? Thanks

I am trying to make some automation functional testing in Vmware using Autoit script, VMs are controlled by a little python script on the host machine (deploy test files into VMs, execute them and collect the results data). But now it seems to be lots of works to do if I want this script to be able to manage and execute a series of test cases.

Thanks a lot!

Cheers,
Zhe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of continuous integration tools that may do what you want.

One implemented in Python that may fit your need is [Buildbot](http://buildbot.net/trac) - it can manage running builds and tests across multiple machines and consolidating the results.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into that! Before I heard from the developers it just can execute some scripts after compiling finishes.